# ajax jquery always running Error;

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax jquery always running error function, althought success function run and i can get session value,i can't run `window.location="profile.php";`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
    var username=$("#usern").val();
    var password=$("#user").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "model/user.php",
        data: {
            user_log : username,
            password : password
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {

              $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
        },
        success: function(json){    

                window.location="profile.php";

        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#error").html("<img src='http://www.chinesecio.com/templates/base/images/loading.gif' /> Loading...")
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

user.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../model/connect.php');
?>
<?php
global $pdo;

    if(isset($_POST['user_log'])) {
        // username and password sent from Form
        $username=$_POST['user_log']; 
        $password=$_POST['password']; 
        $qr= "SELECT * FROM user where username='$username' AND password='$password'" ;
        $stmt= $pdo->query($qr);
        $row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            $_SESSION['name_mem']=$row['username'];
            $_SESSION['level_mem']=$row['level'];
        }
        header("location:../../../../index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Post your server side code

Comment: And what is the actual error?

Comment: wait for me, i will update serverside  code

Comment: @nnnnnn: I can't run to notify of
 success: function(){}

Comment: No, that is the problem. What is the actual error message? jQuery passes details of the error to the error handler, and you even have arguments declared to accept those details, but you're not using them. Use console.log() to log those details and then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax like this,

```
   <script>
        $("#login").click(function(){

         var username=$("#usern").val();
         var password=$("#user").val();
        $.ajax({
                    xhr: function() {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        //progress        
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                            //progress value : you can load progress bar in here                            
                        }, false);
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "model/user.php",
                    data: {'username' : username, 'password' : password},
                    dataType:json,
                    success: function(msg) {
                       //when success //200 ok
                     if(msg.status=="done"){
                    window.location="profile.php";                     
                      }else{    
                       $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> "+msg.massage); 
               }

                    },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   //when error: this statement will execute when fail ajax 
                }
            });
    });
    </script>
```

server side code like this(inside `user.php`),

```
         $username=$_POST['username']; 
         $password=$_POST['password']; 

         ...........


        //$status="fail" or "done"
        //success must be always success
        //$massage= "password or username not match"
$respond=array("success"=>"success","status"=>$status,"massage"=>$massage);
       echo json_encode($respond);
       exit;
```

I hope you useful this.

Comment: Thank you, i will use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line :

```
header("location:../../../../index.php");
```

If above doesn't work, omit this from ajax properties :

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: i forget `header("location:../../../../index.php");`
thank you, i will use